# to locate div by coordinates

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I need to draw a plan of the hall on a site. The hall is drawn in a third-party program. The program gives me a plan of the hall in the form of coordinates of each place:

```
Row Place  X    Y    Widht    Height
1    1     10   10    35       35
```

The plan in a editor looks like:
[image]

I have the following code to draw in the View:

```
 @foreach (var plan in Model.HallPlans)
{
 <div class="place" style="left:@(plan.X)px; top:@(plan.Y)px; height: @(plan.Height)px; width:@(plan.Width)px">@plan.Seat</div>
}
```

This code generate the following:
[image]

I want to reduce the size of div block, for example  twice. If I divide `Height` and `Width` by 2 then it looks like:
[image]

The size of first three rows such as I wanted, but wide place in four row looks not properly(not till the end of the row.). How to correct?. And, How can I reduce the space between `div` ?

PS. some css:

```
div.place {
    display: block;   
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 0 1px 1px;    
   position:absolute;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;     
}
```

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: note: `position:absolute` and `float:left` don't work together. I was going to say, remove the position:absolute and let everything just slide to place, but it looks like your code generates the x and y positions for each `div`. We'll need to look at more code, the code that generates the `div`'s attributes.

Comment: @rgin: if I delete `float` then nothing changes. `x` and `y` not generates, they come from third-party program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>it's very simple, the fourth row is half the width that you want because you divided the `Width` by 2. Just for the forth row **do not** divide the `Width` by 2, but only the `Height`, and it will fill until the end of the row.</strike>

Alternatively have a look at this approach, I just realised this might be what you want:
Where you decide to divide the `Width` and the `Height` by 2, also divide the `X` and `Y` by 2, then output as regular. You will have an end result similar to the original image but half the size.

Comment: Thanks. But how to know when I have to delete or not?

Comment: When the 3rd-party program gives you a `Width` that is more than the `Height` you know that it is not a square. Also have a look at my alternative suggestion, I think this is what you might be after because you also want to reduce the space in between.

Comment: Yes,  I have also divide the `X` and `Y` and all works. Thanks. One more question: now, there are small space between div.How can make it bigger?

Comment: Haha, by adding `n` to `X` where `n` is equal to the increase in space that you want multiplied by the index of the div in it's row, and adding `m` to `Y` where `m` is equal to the space that you want multiplied by the row number. So if you want a space of `5px` and the current div is the 3rd one on the first row then it would get `X = X + (3 * 5);` and `Y = Y + (1 * 5);`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try and add the following in your stylesheet:

```
 div.place:last-child {
        width: 100%
    }
```

Comment: what if in the last row will be one div that have width half row and one small div

Comment: sounds to me like fighting the symptom rather than the problem, just my opinion.